# method to call other methods and handle exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, try-catch, .net-4.5

### Background:

I wrote a C# application that is calling multiple methods from a web service. Methods are being called from loops in Main, from some classes, and so on. Each of these methods may fail because of same reasons:

- Connection timeout
- Web service internal error
- Session expiry

If any of these methods fail, I just need to wait for a few seconds (or call a log-in method), and call them again.

### Problem:

I don't want to write essentially the same try/catch block for every call to all of those methods, so I need another universal method, that would be able to call all the other methods with no regard to it's name and parameters, then catch some common exceptions, call the method again if necessary, and return the values.

Methods delegation ring a bell, but I don't really know how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the Loop in a Try/Catch and put your handle error logic in the catch statement then continue; .

Comment: What type of web service is it? Soap/Restful/WCF If Soap or WCF I assume you are using the built in visual studio add reference that builds proxy classes? If restful are you using the WebClient?

Comment: @Anon That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want universal error handling for each of these methods, and for the ones I'll use in the future, too.

Comment: @RickyJones It's SOAP, and yes, I'm using VS 2012 Web References (not Service References).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want something like this:

```
private T CallWithRetries<T>(Func<T> call)
{
    // TODO: Work out number of retries, etc.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return call();
        }
        catch (FooException e)
        {
            // Determine whether or not to retry, log etc. If this is the
            // last iteration, just rethrow - or keep track of all the exceptions
            // so far and throw an AggregateException containing them.
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Shouldn't get here...");
}
```

Then:

```
// Or whatever you want to do...
int userId = CallWithRetries(() => webService.GetUserId(authentication));
```

You can have a similar method with an `Action` parameter for any calls which don't return a value.

Comment: I like the answer, you could take that a step further. The proxy classes are partial classes you could extend them, to have a more strongly typed call, then use the retry method under the hood.

Comment: Thank you, this is it! But there's one other thing I didn't mention: those methods also have some `out` parameters. Will they be handled appropriately?

Comment: @frikozoid: It depends on what you mean by "appropriately" - but it should work, so long as you give initial values to the variables which you're using for `out` parameters. It's not like a normal method call, because the compiler doesn't "know" that the delegate will be called successfully before the method returns normally.

Comment: Enterprise Library has some good stuff in the Transient Fault Handling block to use patterns like Specification to encapsulate the fault and retry logic policies to invert the dependency. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create method like :

```
private void CallWebMethod(Action methodToBeCalled)
{
    try 
    {           
        methodToBeCalled();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        //Log exception
    }              
}
```

Call methods without any argument using :

```
CallWebMethod(someMethod);
```

Call methods with argument using :

```
CallWebMethod(() => someMethodWithArgument(args));
```

Comment: Thanks. But won't use of `Action` make it break if pass a method with parameters? I guess it should be `Func` instead..

Comment: Not actually you can pass method with parameters but make it break if pass method with return type.